# address doesn't get increased to print a character

Tags: c, string, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{     
    char a[]="kimia";
    a++;
    printf("%c",*a);
}
```

The address is supposed to be incerased by '1' and print 'i' but i am stuck with error "l

value required as increment operand"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An array variable's address cannot be modified.

You can, however, add to an array variable:

```
printf("%c", *(a+1));
```

and increment pointer variables:

```
char *p = a;
p++;
printf("%c", *p);
```

Answer (score 2):

Array names are non modifiable l-values. You can't modify it. But you can use it as a base address in arithmetic operations without modifying it self.

Comment: array name refer to base address .can't we add 1 to base address;

Comment: @user40699 You can, but you cannot modify array name itself.

Answer (score 0):

The compilation error is due to a missing semicolon after:

```
char a[]="kimia"
                ^ should have a ;
```

The ability to advance the pointer can be fixed by changing the declaration to (note that some older compilers would allow the above):

```
char *a = "kimia";
```